# Distinguish between path and markup strings

Tags: javascript

I have a javascript method that takes a single parameter.  That parameter can be a path (in which case the function will use ajax to resolve the variable, a function (which will be called to resolve the variable, or valid markup (which will be used directly).

I'm looking for suggestions for distinguishing between a string that represents a path and a string that represents markup.

Note:  I'm not too concerned if the markup is invalid

Answer (score 0):

Well if you are stuck with the function you got, than you would have to use a regular expression to dtermine what you got. Problem with that, it can be error prone.

You are better off passing in an object and letting the object tell you what you have based on what properties it has.

```
function myMethod( obj ) {
    if (obj.path) {
        console.log("I have a path:", obj.path);
    } else {
        console.log("I have a path:", obj.html);
    }
}

myMethod({"path":"/foo/bar/"});
myMethod({"html":"<p>/foo/bar/</p>"});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```
function validate(param) {

   if (typeof(param) == 'function') {
       console.log('It is a function!')
   } else if (typeof(param) == 'string') {

      if (param.indexOf('http') == 0) {
          console.log('It is a path!')
      } else {
          console.log('It is a markup!')
      }
   }
}
```

It's far from perfect (especially in Path department) but it's a starting point.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/4369k/